# Can someone advise me that can we use MapBox geocoding API to get coordinates of location and store it in the database

Tags: maps, mapbox, geocoding, privacy

My app requires ask user to enter their location and it retrieves the coordinates with MapBox geocoding api. I wanted to know can I store the coordinates in the database so that I can display all user's location on Map.

MapBox Policy.

https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos

You may not use results from the Geocoding API (a) to develop a general database of locations or addresses for any neighborhood, city, state, country, or other such geographic region, or to develop any other general purpose digital map database; (b) to develop or test another geocoding application or API; (c) in connection with navigation products preinstalled or integrated into automobiles by auto manufacturers, auto electronic component manufacturers or auto system integrators; or (d) for in-flight navigation.

Comment: Considering SnapChat's [SnapMap](https://www.mapbox.com/showcase/snap) uses Mapbox in a similar way I think you should be fine. Unless you are selling data or this is a widely used commercial app. It seems those terms are there to prevent someone from creating their own geocoding api (or similar 'stolen' software) with Mapbox.

Comment: Yes It makes sense, Just wanted to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos#[OsOs]:

> 2.8. you may not cache, store, or export any map content from the Services

Comment: 2.7.Unless stated otherwise below:
2.8.you may not cache, store, or export any map content from the Services

Comment: It's not stated that I can't store the coordinates anywhere.